# Laravel 5: adding custom styles/scripts

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This is kind of a stupid question, and I've looked around for similar answers and found some, however they are a bit more specific than what I am asking.

Say I want to include a custom `styles.css` or `scripts.js` file, would I just create a css/js folder in `resources/views` folder, and then call to them in my blade.php files like I would normally do in an HTML file when not using Laravel?

Example: `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">`

Or is there a different approach to this in Laravel?

Comment: The way I said works, but they do have some more complicated asset managers to deal with things, depending on the complexity of your application, so you may want to look into those first.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Put your css files into the `public` folder like `public/css/styles.css`

Use the `asset()` function to add `css`, `javascript` or `images` into your blade template.

**For Style Sheets**

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

or

```
<link href="{{ URL::asset('css/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

**For Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/scripts.js') }}"></script>
```

or

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/scripts.js') }}"></script>
```

You may also be interested to have a look at Laravel's [Elixir](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/elixir) to process your styles and javascript.

Comment: What's the difference between `asset` and `URL::asset`?

Comment: one is shorter than the other ;) The `asset()` function is a helper and shorter than using the laravel facade `URL::asset()`. The result is the same. It's a personal preference thing I guess.

Answer (score 1):

put your style.css file in inside css folder named: /css AND your  js file inside js folder named: /jsput below code in your html file.

**Your css files**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/yourstylesheet.css') }}" />
```

**And js files**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
```